# Swift: WebKit View / WebView disable plug-ins like JavaScript or Flash

Tags: swift, webview, webkit, interface-builder

I'm using a WebKit View (within a Mac OSX App) and want to disable plug-ins like JavaScript or Flash. I unchecked the options in the Interface Builder, but that resulted in no notable effect. Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't figure out why the check-boxes in the Interface Builder had no effect, however, here's the programmatically solution:

```
customWebKitView.preferences.plugInsEnabled = false
customWebKitView.preferences.loadsImagesAutomatically = false
customWebKitView.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = false
```